# CakePHP beforeFind

Tags: ajax, cakephp, callback

I am using cake's callback method, beforeFind which adds some conditions to each query dynamically. All went well at first and thought it will minimize development time.. until I made an ajax request which performs a find on some models.. It doesn't seem to work when this happens.. 
Basically I am adding some query conditions

```
public function beforeFind($query){

        if(empty($this->aff)){
            throw new Exception("Username cannot be null.");
        }

        //set active flag
        $query["conditions"]["MsGa.active_flag"] = "active";


        if(empty($query["conditions"]["OR"])){
            $query["conditions"]["OR"] = array();
        }

        $query["conditions"]["OR"][] = array("FIND_IN_SET('".$this->aff."', MsGa.aff)");
        $query["conditions"]["OR"][] = array("MsGa.aff" => "");


        if(!empty($this->type)){
            $query["conditions"]["MsGa.type"] = $this->type;
        }

        return $query;
}
```

Would it normally work in an ajax request, when a find is done on a model (ofcourse.. )? If not how so?  Is it possible to explicitly invoke it?

**[EDIT]**

Here's the function that is called when the ajax request is initiated :

```
 public function getResultsCount($data){
            return $this->find("count", array(
                "conditions" => $this->_setupConditions($data)
            ));
        }
```

And

`_setupConditions` returns an array of query conditions...

The function which returns the result set :

```
public function getResults($data){
            return $this->find("all", array(
                "conditions" => $this->_setupConditions($data)
            ));
        }
```

Whenever I initiate the ajax request and the query is executed, a certain count is returned. And when the actual result set is returned, there are less records then actually displayed by the count function. . So my thinking was that it might be that the beforeFind() is not being executed, since if I comment out this callback, the count and the number of records on the result set  are equal. I am a bit baffled

Comment: Models know nothing about request type, ajax or otherwise. If your beforeFind is not being triggered it means the model's find() method is not being called or you have made an error in mode's filename / classname and it's not being loaded.

Comment: Thanks for you comment @ADmad.. Ok so theoretically it should work?   I'm sure the model's find method is being called since im getting back the data. must be something else then..

Comment: You would get back data even if AppModel instance was being used for your model name. Do debug(get_class($this->MyModel)); in your controller. It's should return your model classname and not "AppModel".

Comment: Hmm.. yes but the data I get back is as expected.. The only problem is that when I initiate the ajax call, a php function is called, which should run a query to count a number of records in a result set, based on some criteria.. I will update the question tomorrow to include the `find`query..

Comment: @ADmad, See updated question for a clear idea of my problem